# Issue while processing a line using awk in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am running [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) command on each line of a file. Two sample lines of file are

```
$HOME:1:2
$HOME:1:2 3
```

I am expecting output of above two lines after running my command as:

```
/home/mjain8:1:2
/home/mjain8:1:2 3
```

The awk command I am running is `awk 'BEGIN{cmd="realpath "}{cmd$0|getline;print $0;}' FS=':' OFS=':'`

Now, when I run the command on first line it runs fine and gives me the desired output. But for line 2 of file (shown above) the output is `/home/mjain8:1:2` (and **NOT** `/home/mjain8:1:2 3`). That is the output only contains line before space.

Can someone please point what am I doing wrong. Also, in case you have suggestion to use any other command please let me know same too. I have been struggling to do same using awk since last 2 days.

I want to make it portable so that it run on as many shells as possible.

Comment: Where is the Input_file in `awk` command? Is it typo or you missed it while running it too? Kindly confirm. Also it will be good if you could mention example output of `realpath` and your sample Input_file with sample expected output it will be good for us to get complete question's requirement.

Comment: Sorry for wording the question poorly. I am running the command on file but for clarity I have just mentioned one sample input which is ''$HOME:1:2 3". I will edit question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With shell's `while` loop it will be much simpler, could you please try following. It worked fine for me.

```
while IFS=':' read -r path rest
do
   real=$(realpath "$path")
   echo "$real:$rest"
done < "Input_file"
```

Above code has `real` variable to first have `realpath` command's value and then it prints its output along with `rest` variable, in case you want to directly print them as per tripleee's comment use following then.

```
while IFS=':' read -r path rest
do
   echo "$(realpath "$path"):$rest"
done < "Input_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl-one liner also, you could do it easily

```
> export HOME=/home/mjain8
> cat home.txt
$HOME:1:2
$HOME:1:2 3
>  perl -F: -lane ' {$F[0]=$ENV{HOME} ;print join(":",@F)  } ' home.txt
/home/mjain8:1:2
/home/mjain8:1:2 3
> perl -F: -lane ' {$F[0]=$ENV{HOME} if $F[0]=~/\$HOME/;print join(":",@F)  } ' home.txt # if you need to explicity check if it is HOME
/home/mjain8:1:2
/home/mjain8:1:2 3
>
```